# Default function parameter is not initialized in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, parameters, default-value

The following code

```
def score_track(details, result_details, top_score=200):
    if top_score < 120:
        # do smth
    return None
```

works in Python 2 but throws exception in Python 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "function.py", line 280, in <module>
    search_result.get('score'))
  File "ImportList.py", line 131, in score_track
    if top_score < 120:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

If I initialize `top_score` explicitly it goes fine.

`score_track` function is called like this:

```
add_song(details,score_track(details,details))
```

`search_result` list is constructed like this:

```
  search_results = [] 
  dlog('search details: '+str(details)) 

  lib_album_match = False 
  if details['artist'] and details['title'] and search_personal_library:
      lib_results = [item for item in library if s_in_s(details['artist'],item.get('artist')) and s_in_s(details['title'],item.get('title'))] 
      dlog('lib search results: '+str(len(lib_results))) 
      for result in lib_results: 
          if s_in_s(result['album'],details['album']): 
              lib_album_match = True 
          item = {} 
          item[u'track'] = result 
          item[u'score'] = 200 
          search_results.append(item)
```

What is wrong? I didn't find any information about different behavior of default parameter values in Python3 vs Python2.

Comment: What is `search_result`? How do you call `score_track`? Can you post enough code so we are able to *reproduce* your error?

Comment: You didn't provide enough detail on how you **call** the function. I suspect that the `search_result.get('score')` part returns `None` (there is no `'score'` key in the `search_result` dictionary on Python 3), and that is passed in as the value for `top_score`.

Comment: Put differently, your analysis of what is wrong is incorrect. The default value for `top_score` works just fine, but if you pass in an explicit value for the parameter, then the default *won't apply*. `None` is still a value here.

Comment: Added function call and `search_result` list construction, but this is irrelevant here, I exactly found out the root cause of exception

Comment: `but if you pass in an explicit value for the parameter, then the default *won't apply*. None is still a value here` nope, I do not pass explicit None value there. Actually I am trying to rewrite [this script](https://github.com/soulfx/gmusic-playlist/blob/master/ImportList.py) on Python 3.